# Hibernate : Using Serializable and transient which best pratice?

Tags: json, spring-boot, hibernate

I've a problem to create the mapping with an old database.

I have an object with a lot of List and Collections. So I've decided to implements serializable and here is my workflow:

1- put @JsonIgnore on the @ManyToOne
2- add "transient" on all Collection or List
3- wait the memory limit and/or the recursive alert to find the next object who give me the loop
4- restart on the new object from the step 1

Is it a good way to get a good mapping?

Comment: What is your... goal? Old database suggests you have existing data - are you adding hiberante mapping to be able to work with it, is that it? Where did the object with lots of collections come from, and what is it's relation to the data? How does json come into play in all of this?

Comment: Yes, I'm confronted to an old database which works with an old mapping with a dao,  pojo's and hibernate 4. The transition to hibernate 5 is very complicated, maybe impossible. That's why I'm trying to re-map with spring boot and hibernate 5...

Comment: maybe is there a tips to don't wait 10/15min to get the error. Cause I'm loosing a lot of time to solve each problem ^^